# Possible to Subclass UILocalNotification and Change Default "Close" Button Text and Method?

Tags: objective-c, overriding, subclass, uilocalnotification

Searching for a way to change the **"Close"** button text/functionality of a **UILocalNotification**...

I've found that it's **impossible** to access/call the text/function from another object, although **subclassing** UILocalNotification should allow implementation method **overrides**... not to mention the **creation of an accessor** to get/set the **"Close"** button text field.

What do you guys think about this? *What would Apple?*

Has anyone tried?...

**EDIT: 12/21/2011 12:01 PM**

The question that I'm asking involves an understanding of oop: late/early binding, dynamic method lookup, and declared type vs. runtime type field and method handling.

Subclassing of UILocalNotification **does** work...

`UILocalNotificationExampleSubclass * example = [UILocalNotificationExampleSubclass init];`

...and the device **does** create an object, however, with type `UILocalNotification` and not `UILocalNotificationExampleSubclass`.

I'm looking for insight into the UILocalNotification.m file's methods.

If it **does not** have its own methods, what object *(name please)* takes an instance of a UILocalNotification, uses its fields, and displays the object *(name please)* we see on screen?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `UILocalNotification` is just a storage for the notification's information. It does not perform anything.

Moreover your application does not display the notification. Another process does. So subclassing `UILocalNotification` is just useless.

**EDIT** at December 22nd, 17:53 UTC+1:

Yes, you can subclass `UILocalNotification`. But `UILocalNotification` is an abstract class and none of its properties is implemented. The `alloc` method is overridden so it returns an instance of `UILocalNotification`, a private subclass. That's why you cannot instantiate `UILocalNotificationExampleSubclass`.

But still, there is not point to subclass `UILocalNotification` because when you schedule a notification using [`-[UIApplication scheduleLocalNotification:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/scheduleLocalNotification%3a) or present the notification immediately using [`-[UIApplication presentLocalNotification:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/presentLocalNotificationNow%3a), the operating system **copies** the notification.

That copy is stored in another process managed by the system, which uses its own private storage mechanism. A `UILocalNotification` is just a storage for a bunch of properties that is destined to get serialized and sent from the application to the operating system.

Now, we have that other process storing all the scheduled local notifications and waiting for a notification to fire. When that happens, that process will check if your application is in the foreground.

- If your application is not in the foreground, that other process, which is totally out of our control, will create an alert and display the notification. We cannot customize that alert in any way, except by using the properties of the `UILocalNotification` class.
- If your application is in the foreground, the notification will be sent back to the application that will create a new instance of `UILocalNotification`. Then, the `UIApplication` shared instance will access its `delegate` property and check if that delegate implements [`application:didReceiveLocalNotification:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application%3adidReceiveLocalNotification%3a). If it does, you get the notification back and can do anything you want with that notification. For example, you may choose to display the notification using an alert view.

Configuring and displaying the alert view can be done like this:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    UIAlertView *alertView =
    [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Alert", nil)
                               message:NSLocalizedString(notification.alertBody, nil)
                              delegate:nil
                     cancelButtonTitle:nil
                     otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", nil), nil];
    [alertView show];
    [alertView release]; // unless your project uses Automatic Reference Counting
}
```

I hope this longer response did answer your question, *if what I'm saying is true*.

Comment: *If what you're saying is true...*

Do you know what class takes an instance of the `UILocalNotification` to construct the alert we see on screen? I'd like you to drop some knowledge on me please. Looking for some facts outside of the class reference that Apple makes public.

Comment: If your application is in the foreground, the `UIApplication`'s delegate can implement `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` and display a custom alert view. If your application is in the background (or not running), the system displays the alert and you cannot change the name of the close button.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, but it doesn't answer my question.