# Find out when a repeating UILocalNotification was fired

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I have a `UILocalNotification` that is set to start at `2012-06-18 10:00` with a repeat interval of 1 minute.

At `2012-06-18 10:05` 5 notifications would have been triggered. The user would then choose notification number 3. The notification should have been fired at `2012-06-18 10:02`.

In my `- application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` method. How can I programatically get this fire date from notification number 3 which should be `2012-06-18 10:02`. I know I can get the intitial/start fireDate property from the `UILocalNotification` but I'm not interested in that. I'm interested to know the fireDate of **this** repeating notification (not the intial/start fireDate).

If someone can explain to me how to find out which repeating `UILocalNotification` was fired without parsing the `- description` of the notification I will give you some of my hard earned bounty.

Comment: I dont think it is really possible since all the information passed (even on the userInfo dictionary) is configured before scheduled. So i dont think it is meant for this purpose. But i could be wrong, just speaking about my experience.

Comment: I don't think this is possible either. The thing to take note of from the documentation is that each recurring notification is not a different notification, it is the same notification rescheduled again for another time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have given this a bit more thought, and as I said in my comment it doesnt seem possible because of the way notifications are handled.

You create one and fire immediately or schedule it.

A notification is just the storage of some information which means it is only meant to be read for its properties.

The application receives the notification through

```
application:didReceiveLocalNotification:
```

In where only the [UILocalNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) itself is passed. This notification ONLY has a bunch of properties which were set at the start.

The repeat interval is only used to re-notify the user, it doesnt change what the notification has inside.

This comes to the conclusion that for the behavior you expect to achieve you would have to fire different notifications if you expect to pass different information or perform different actions.

(Sub-classing is also not useful as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/8583329/1068522)

Comment: So it seems that the only option I have then is to parse the `-description` of `UILocalNotification`? How can I do this the best way to ensure that my application still works if Apple decides to change the `-description` method of `UILocalNotification`?

Comment: that would be in the way you parse the description, Ideally speaking you want to look for something that "looks like" the fired keyword and take whatever value is ahead. All these is acomplished with the NSString convenience methods and perhaps the NSScaner, there are several ways actually. Would you mind posting 2 or 3 NSlogged descriptions of these scheduled notifications?

Comment: Here is what they look like: `<UIConcreteLocalNotification: 0x613e060>{fire date = 2010-11-29 03:53:52 GMT, time zone = America/Denver (MST) offset -25200, repeat interval = 16, next fire date = 2010-11-30 03:53:52 GMT}`

Comment: But did you check the difference in triggering the other notification of the same original fired one? to specify correctly the difference between triggers like in your situation.

Comment: what you seek is to be able to distinguish between which of the 5 notifications was activated right? I dont remember very well but im not sure if the description actually changes between which of the 5 you activate. I just want to confirm that. IF it does change then its just a matter creating a substring between the first encounter of fire date and repeat interval. There are really too many ways and as you said apple may change it. You would need to experiment here, http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsstring_Class/Reference/NSString.html

Comment: But I really have no way of telling you how it could be reliable in the future. Perhaps you could wait and someone with a different approach could help you out.

Comment: The `-description` of a repeating `UILocalNotification` is different depending on which you triggered from the notification center. What will differ is the "next fire date" part in the description. But how can I "safely" parse this string even if Apple changed implementation? `- (NSString *)parseDescription:(NSString *)description { if(//description doesn't contain some text) { // then Apple changed implementation return @"ChangedImpl"; } else { //parse the string and return it }}` Like so?

Comment: Yes exactly, if you go for the parsing approach you want to give several posibilities to try to salvage the situation. the way you wrote it sounds perfectly fine for me, but at the end of the day it is still a gamble. You might wanna try the other solution proposed on the answers but it is still a gamble since apple runs your code on their static analyzer which looks for undocumented/private API calls and rejects automatically. Honestly the best solution is to re think how you do this, firing several notifications sounds more secure to me.

Comment: You can fire many with some criteria and just cancel all in queue when one has been selected. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158264/cancel-uilocalnotification

Answer (score 1):

The best alternate solution to getting the fireDate of the **UILocalNotification** is to calculate the date.
Given that you have an initial fireDate, you can use the repeated interval to calculate the fireDate of a given notification.

> 1.Start with the initial fire date
>   2.Get the notification number/index of the notification you have
>   
>   3.Multiply the repeated interval by the index and add it onto your initial fire date

However, date calculating, as mentioned in the below link, is tricky due to time zones and "other nasty things."

Here's a helpful link:

[How to grab the NEXT fire date from a UILocalNotification object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301184/how-to-grab-the-next-fire-date-from-a-uilocalnotification-object)


And of course, there is the final, fall back solution of parsing the `description` method. Using `[notification.fireDate description]` However, as you probably know, it is NEVER a good idea to do so because the formatting may change in the future, thus breaking your code.

Hope this helped!

**Edit:**
Example: Okay, so say my first initial fireDate was `2012-06-18 10:00`
I know that my repeated interval is every ONE minute, right?

So say, that the user taps uilocalnotification number 3, then that means TWO minutes should have passed! 
THEREFORE, the time for that specific notification is: `2012-06-18 10:02`

Does this make sense?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't think you understood my question. I know how to calculate future dates by using the `repeatInterval` but that is not my question. My question is how I can uniquely identify which repeating `UILocalNotification` the user chosed to view/open. But thanks for your attempt to give me an answer :)

Comment: Can you get the notification number of a specific notification? Please look at my edit! Thanks!

Comment: Yes that makes sense, that is what I have written in my question essentially. But you're still not answering my question ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Q:**

> If someone can explain to me how to find out which repeating
>   UILocalNotification was fired without parsing the - description of the
>   notification I will give you some of my hard earned bounty.

**A: The easiest way:**

```
- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:notification.repeatInterval fromDate:notification.fireDate toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
    NSLog(@"Notification #%d", [comps minute] + 1);
}
```

---

**Q:** How to get that "next fire date" from `description` without parsing?

**A:** There is private/undocumented function for this: `nextFireDateForLastFireDate`

```
- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"next: %@", [notification nextFireDateForLastFireDate:[NSDate date]]);
}
```

**Q:** Maybe there is some kind of count in notifications? property or method?

**A:** There's undocumented properties:

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) int totalRepeatCount;
@property (assign, nonatomic) int remainingRepeatCount;
```

But they seem to have always same value: `UILocalNotificationInfiniteRepeatCount`. Both of them is managed by **operating system**, so overwriting of this properties or underlying instance variable does nothing. Moreover, **nothing changes inside** UILocalNotifications from firing to firing, there's no way to distinguish one UILocalNotification from another (except address in memory). **Next fireDate** is calculated basing on current time.