# "unrecognized selector sent to instance" property setter

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, unrecognized-selector

I have a custom class that inherits from `UILocalNotification`, it's has a `Store` object property (a class that inherits from `NSObject`):

**customLocalNotification.h**:

`@property (strong,nonatomic) Store *store;`

But when I try to set "Store" object in the `viewController` like this:

```
customLocalNotification *notification=[[customLocalNotification alloc] init];
notification.store=store; //Crashes here
```

**Edit**: I'll use `userInfo` dictionary to save my `Store` object, but when I try to do it it crashes with this error message:

```
2016-02-11 15:55:26.132 App[13861:3606796] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'unable to serialize userInfo: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3851 "Property list invalid for format: 200 (property lists cannot contain objects of type 'CFType')" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Property list invalid for format: 200 (property lists cannot contain objects of type 'CFType')}'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c196e65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010bc0fdeb objc_exception_throw + 48
2   UIKit                               0x000000010cbd5ba5 -[UIConcreteLocalNotification userInfo] + 0
3   App                            0x00000001088cb65b -[monitorLocationViewController createNotificationWithStore:andArounders:] + 683
4   App                            0x00000001088cb1ed -[monitorLocationViewController sendNotificationIfNeededForStore:] + 397
5   App                            0x00000001088cb021 -[monitorLocationViewController locationManager:didEnterRegion:] + 145
6   App                            0x00000001088cae9c __68-[monitorLocationViewController locationManager:didUpdateLocations:]_block_invoke + 284
7   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c0f59ff __51-[__NSSetM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 79
8   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c0f590a -[__NSSetM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 202
9   App                            0x00000001088cad02 -[monitorLocationViewController locationManager:didUpdateLocations:] + 402
10  CoreLocation                        0x000000010a8c5177 CLClientGetCapabilities + 20882
11  CoreLocation                        0x000000010a8c15d3 CLClientGetCapabilities + 5614
12  CoreLocation                        0x000000010a8bc0cd CLClientInvalidate + 923
13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c0c2a1c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c0b86a5 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c0b7e02 __CFRunLoopRun + 850
16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c0b7828 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
17  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010ed92ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
18  UIKit                               0x000000010c543610 UIApplicationMain + 171
19  App                            0x00000001088dedef main + 111
20  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010dbbe92d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Does anyone know why is crashing?

Thank you!

Comment: Somehow you're not getting your subclass of `UILocalNotification`.  What does your `init` method look like?

Comment: As an aside, it probably makes more sense to store additional properties in some other way.  `UILocalNotification` objects are passed to iOS, and your custom classes likely do not survive the transition.

Comment: @Avi I'm not overriding `init` on `customLocalNotification` so I guess it is the default.

Comment: @Avi How can I store a store property to an `UILocalNotification` object without a custom class?

Comment: did you synthesised the store

Comment: @NileshMahajan I've just tried it and I still have the same problem.

Comment: It seems that you can't really subclass `UILocalNotification`, it's class will always be `UIConcreteLocationNotification`. I tested it with inheriting from `UILocalNotification` and then from `UIView`, and it's class is not changed for inheriting from `UILocalNotification`. You may also be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580782/possible-to-subclass-uilocalnotification-and-change-default-close-button-text You may want also put custom data in `userInfo` (NSDictionary) for your unknown purposes...

Comment: I've just realized I can use `userInfo` dictionary to transfer data with the notification

Comment: @Larme I'll user usrInfo but I've updated the post with its error message, please take a look

Comment: I can't think of *any* good reason to subclass UILocalNotification. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @NileshMahajan I'll user usrInfo but I've updated the post with its error message, please take a look

Comment: @Eiko I'll user usrInfo but I've updated the post with its error message, please take a look

Comment: @Avi I'll user userInfo but I've updated the post with its error message, please take a look

Comment: Well, without knowing `Store` it's hard to guess, but the error message is quite explicit. But how do you set it exactly? You should do `notification.userInfo = @{@"Store":store};`?

Comment: @Larme `notification.userInfo=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:store forKey:@"store"];`

Answer (score 1):

`UILocalNotifications` are designed to contain some **lightweight** data. That is, `userInfo` can contain [property list encodable](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/PropertyList.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH44) items only. And I'd add that the whole thing is not designed to throw heavy objects around, but just pass some contextual info around that you need to handle the notification when it arrives (i.e. some identifiers, a number etc.).

Comment: How can I pass an object like `Store` object (a custom class with a few properties) through `UILocalNotification`? (I need to know to what store the notification sent).

Comment: Encode your store into an NSDictionary, and unwrap it when the notification arrives. Of course, the whole process makes only sense if the Store object is not connected to any other part of the app in a way that can't be restored easily.

Comment: `Store` object into an `NSDictionary` object into `userInfo` dictionary object?

Comment: Yes. Typically you might just store for example the identifier of the Store, and rebuild it then. Again, this is not suitable for complex object graphs. Remember, your new instance does not have any connection with the original object, and it often exists in a completely new environment (i.e. after app launch).

Comment: Oh, so how can I get the original object using the notification?

Comment: You don't. Easy as that. And it doesn't make sense, because generally an object could be connected to **anything**. Don't fight the framework - what ever you try to accomplish, this is not the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I am agree with Eiko. 
You may add arbitrary key-value pairs to this dictionary. However, the keys and values must be valid property-list types; if any are not, an exception is raised.
check below two links
  [UILocalNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/userInfo)
[Valid Property list types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/PropertyList.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH44)

To solve your issue you can try this
1) Create NSDictionary for your object store with all properties as key-value pair ,which you want to pass with UILocalNotification
2) set dictionary object userinfo dictionary
3) parse and load your new dictionary and create Store object where you want to use it.

Comment: Is there any option I can get the original object passed?

Comment: You may have some unique key property in Store class. just pass that key as string with UILocalNotification and fetch your Store object using that key.

Comment: you can't pass the original object with userInfo dictionary. So you have to find some alternate way for this